# How to add a line break?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

```js
let errores = Object.values(this.errores)
let stringError = ""
for (let index = 0; index < errores.length; index++) {
  stringError += errores[index] + "\n"
}
return stringError
```

How can get a line break which basically returns a string?

- This is on ***angular ionic*** with an alert controller
- I'm putting this error on the message

I tried whit a `br` but, I'm not getting a line break.

Comment: Can you provide the data of ```this.errores```? Or add image/sample of error message that will show.

Answer (score 4):

Hi i solved this by adding

on app.module.ts this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot({ innerHTMLTemplatesEnabled: true }),
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
],
```

setting  innerHTMLTemplatesEnabled: true will enable to use IonicSafeString on IONIC 7, so when i return string will be like this:

[image]